# учебная задача на инициализацию статических переменных

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Есть учебная задача . Как эту задачу сделать мне непонятно. Я постарался сделать дословно что просят, но свести к результату не выходит (то есть добиться что просят в последнем предложении текста задачи)

[image: первая часть упражнения]

[image: вторая часть упражнения]

вот моя реализация . я конструкторы сделал более информативными (то есть первый конструктор стал вовсе не по умолчанию, у него появился параметр и у второго конструктора добавился ещё и второй параметр - этого в задаче не просят (это для себя)), выводя какая переменная запросила конструктор . суть задачи в том как понимаю, что при компоновки последовательность файлов может быть разной. Но в любом случае test() в main выдаст true потому что рекурсивно функция выполнится вплоть до A1 в которой как бы конструктор по умолчанию (на самом деле я его сделал с параметром для информативности) .
То есть я подозреваю , что я неверно понял и соответственно реализовал задачу.

s4.cpp

```
#include "H1.h"

extern Mirror A1;
Mirror A2("A2", &A1);
```

s1.cpp

```
#include "H1.h"

extern Mirror A2;
Mirror A3("A3", &A2);
```

s2.cpp

```
#include "H1.h"

extern Mirror A3;
Mirror A4("A4", &A3);
```

s3.cpp

```
#include "H1.h"
Mirror A1("A1");
```

s5.cpp

```
#include "H1.h"

extern Mirror A4;
Mirror A5("A5",&A4);

void main() {
    std::cout << A5.test() << std::endl;
}
```

и заголовочник :

```
#include <iostream>
class Mirror {
    Mirror* M;
    std::string MNAME;
    bool b;
public:
    Mirror(std::string var) : M(0), b(true), MNAME(var){
        std::cout << var <<"(default)"<< std::endl;
        
    }
    Mirror(std::string var, Mirror* M1) : M(M1), b(false), MNAME(var) {
        std::cout << var << std::endl;
        
    }
    bool test() {
        if (M != 0) return M->test(); else return b;
        }
};
```

Comment: Возможно тут подразумевалось отстреливание ноги из-за SIOF (что могло бы произойти, если вызвать `test()` в конструкторе), но автор задания умудрился отстрелить ногу из без SIOF. Поищите менее бестолковую книжку...

Comment: @user7860670  что такое siof ?

Comment: Static Initialization Order Fiasco - порядок вызова конструкторов глобальных объектов в разных единицах трансляции не определен. А обращение к объекту, конструктор которого еще не вызван - неопределенное поведение.

Comment: @user7860670 совершенно верно, это и предполагается и тема про это. однако, при любом порядке все равно все проинициализируется  корректно. скажем я добился того, что s3.cpp с конструктором для A1  у меня сработает 3 по счету. а до этого отработает Mirror A2("A2", &A1); в результате в конце концов всё от A1 , до A5 пудет подвержено своим конструкторам.

Comment: У вас это работает, так как test вызывается после завершения стадии динамической инициализации, а не во время ее.

Comment: @user7860670  мною задача сделана верно, как вы считаете ??? у меня цель добиться , чтобы A5.test() выдал false. как это сделать я не пойму ((

Comment: В таком сценарии A5.test() не должен выдать false, автор облажался...

Comment: @user7860670 это хреново.  так как на основе этого делаются ещё 2 важные задачи

Comment: @user7860670 а в каком сценарии выдало бы false ?

Comment: Ни в каком. Либо оно перебирает все объекты и выдает true добравшись до последнего (который был инициализирован конструктором по-умолчанию), либо получаете Неопределенное Поведение.

Comment: А откуда эта задача?

Comment: @user7860670 это Брюс Эккель 2004 год.

Comment: Есть у кого-нибудь английское издание? Подозреваю плохой перевод.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy : In a header file, create a class Mirror that contains two
data members: a pointer to a Mirror object and a bool.
Give it two constructors: the default constructor initializes the bool to true and the Mirror pointer to
zero. The second constructor takes as an argument a
pointer to a Mirror object, which it assigns to the
object’s internal pointer; it sets the bool to false. Add a
member function test( ): if the object’s pointer is
nonzero, it returns the value of test( ) called through the
pointer.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy  If the pointer is zero, it returns the bool. Now
create five cpp files, each of which includes the Mirror
header. The first cpp file defines a global Mirror object
using the default constructor. The second file declares the
object in the first file as extern, and defines a global
Mirror object using the second constructor, with a
pointer to the first object.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Keep doing this until you reach
the last file, which will also contain a global object
definition. In that file, main( ) should call the test( )
function and report the result. If the result is true, find
out how to change the linking order for your linker and
change it until the result is false.

Comment: Нашел английское издание - таже проблема: всё работает, решения нет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробую перевести задачу на человеческий язык. Это задача на то как влияет порядок статической инициализации на поведение программы.

В формулировке из картинки задача неразрешима. Каков бы ни был порядок инициализации пяти объектов, в момент когда мы попадаем в `main` они все созданы и все запомнили правильные указатели из цепочки. Когда вы вызовете `A5.test()` вся цепочка будет пройдена и в ответе будет `true` из `A1`.

Чтобы демострация сработала надо сделать две вещи:

**1.** Надо убрать `std::string` из объекта. Задача предполагает, что объект является почти [POD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure). Добавив `name` вы нарушили это условие. Если объект почти POD, то компоновщик заполнив объекты нулями сделает их полуживыми. Заполнение нулями поля `std::string` просто сломает его.

Объекты будут "полуживыми" так как стандарт запрещает их использовать до вызова конструктора. Но идея задачи как раз в том чтобы сделать это.

**2.** Надо переделать конструктор:

```
Mirror(Mirror* M1, const std::string& name) : M(M1), b(M1->test()) {
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
}
```

Я вызвал `M1->test()` в конструкторе. Если объект `M1` ещё не сконструирован, то он заполнен нулями. Метод `test` вернёт `false`, который мы скопируем в конструируемый объект.

Если в нашей цепочке будет хотя бы одна пара инициализаций в "неправильном" порядке, то в `main` вернётся `false`. Если все инициализации будут упорядочены `A1, A2, A3, A4, A5`, то вернётся `true`.

Ключевой ингредиент задачи - исполнение кода (или чтение данных из) объекта который ещё не конструировался.

Comment: Объект не должен быть POD, собственно объект с конструктором им все равно не является. Нулями заполняются все статические объекты еще до фазы динамической инициализации. Но это не позволяет обращаться с ними, как с инициализированными. А 2 приведет к неопределенному поведению. *"исполнение кода (или чтение данных из) объекта который ещё не конструировался"* - это ключевой момент отстреливания ноги.

Comment: @user7860670, а как вы сделаете зависимость от порядка инициализации без UB?

Comment: Никак не сделаю. Я дорожу своими ногами :D

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Mirror(Mirror* M1, const std::string& name) : M(M1), b(M1->test())

вот это жестоко : b(M1->test()
)))

Comment: @АндрейГуренков, согласен. Чтобы пример из Эккеля "заработал" нужен код исполняющий или читающий данные, которые ещё не были сконструированы.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy тогда может в каждый файл понапихать тестов, скажем для s2.cpp  вот так #include "H1.h"

extern Mirror A3;
Mirror A4("A4", &A3); A4.test();

Comment: Зачем? Они исполнятся без всякого следа. И нормально исполнятся: вы ничего не заметите. Статические объекты до старта программы заполняются нулями. В вашем случае это будет `false` и `nullptr`. `test()` на таком объекте вернёт `false`.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy тогда не знаю (

Comment: Я хотя бы попытался.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy что значит это : нужен код исполняющий или читающий данные, которые ещё не были сконструированы ? то есть это невозможно так как Статические объекты до старта программы заполняются нулями. В нашем случае это будет false и nullptr. test() . Верно я понимаю ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117571/discussion-between-stanislav-volodarskiy-and--).